# Java hex byte array converting to integer without converting to String first

Tags: java, arrays, int, hex, byte

I'm trying to convert byte array which holds hex values.

```
byte[] bytes = {48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 51, 51, 99}
```

for example : 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 51, 51, 99 is 0000033c and converted to int is 828.
The only way to convert is converting it to **String** and then parse integer from String.

```
 public static int ConvertValueFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        String b = new String(bytes);
        return Converter.ConvertHexToInt(b);
    }
```

The main problem here is performance, calling it many times can cause performance issues. When trying parse int value from byte array I get massive numbers, thats why I'm parsing from String, to get the correct value.
Is there a better way or solution to this ?

Comment: Something doesn't add up in your logic. Why are you storing what is essentially a **string representation** of a **hexadecimal value** in a **byte array**? Your byte array should probably look like this: `byte[] bytes = {0, 0, 3, 60}`, or even just `{3, 60}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java

Comment: I have a large one string hex value which contains up to 2000+ characters. What I'm doing is splitting them to smaller parts to get the int value.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't need String value, I need int.

Comment: There's no need to base yourself on the character values of your hex string. Every two characters represent one byte, so you should parse them as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst it's very unclear why you would represent the data in this way, it's easy to transform without using a string:

```
int v = 0;
for (byte b : bytes) {
  v = 16 * v + Character.getNumericValue(b);
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/69I2cW)

Comment: This kind of works and parsing negative values as well. Can you explain me please how this for loop works ?

Comment: `0x123` is `(((1) * 16 + 2) * 16) + 3`.